# Как прочитать vbaproject.bin?

Tags: excel, vba

Можно ли как-то прочитать код внутри файла `vbaproject.bin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вот тут](https://www.decalage.info/vba_tools) обзор инструментов по работе с VBA. В том числе и [olevba](https://github.com/decalage2/oletools/wiki/olevba), входящий в [oletools](https://github.com/decalage2/oletools), которые умеют декомпилировать VBA-код.

Пример использования `olevba`:

```py
from oletools.olevba import VBA_Parser

vbaparser = VBA_Parser('my_file_with_macros.xlsx')

for (filename, stream_path, vba_filename, vba_code) in vbaparser.extract_macros():
    print '-'*79
    print 'Filename    :', filename
    print 'OLE stream  :', stream_path
    print 'VBA filename:', vba_filename
    print '- '*39
    print vba_code
```

Comment: Это код на Питонце?

Comment: Да. `oletools` - это библиотека python